# "appreciate for that"/"for it"?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

> If you wish further suggestions for changes, we appreciate for that.

Should this be "for it" or "for that" or nothing?

Comment: I think the idiom is *appreciate it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer something like:

Further suggestions for changes are appreciated.

We would appreciate any further suggestions for changes.

We welcome any further suggestions for changes.

The grammatically correct version of your sentence would be "If you wish to make further suggestions for changes, we would appreciate it."